# Changing grid with media queries

Tags: html, css, css-grid

It could be that I don't have a grasp on css grid, but I am trying to have these two layouts, one for mobile and one for desktop. I have tried using media queries to create two different grids but the desktop one ends up messed up (assuming because there's already a grid)
I've attached the two layouts below, Would not using grid be better?

[image: Mobile View]

[image]

Comment: please provide the code that you already have. Its easier fixing what you have then inventing it new

Comment: start with a block layout for mobile and add a mediaquerie to turn it into a 2 column grid for bigger screen, it will be less confusing to you

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Ahh a lovely idea, much less confusing thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should check [grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)

Suppose the elements structure is like so:

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="heading"></div>
 <div class="image"></div>
 <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

For Web view :

```css
.container{
grid-template-areas: 
            "image heading"
            "image content"
}
```

For Mobile View

```css
.container{
grid-template-areas: 
            "heading"
            "image"
            "content"
}
```

Specify area names :

```css
.heading{
   grid-area: heading
}

.image{
   grid-area: image
}

 .content{
   grid-area: content
}
```

Now simply toggle `container` class `grid-template-areas` using @media query

```css
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  .container{
    grid-template-areas: 
            "image heading"
            "image content"
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  .container{
    grid-template-areas: 
            "heading"
            "image"
            "content"
   }
```

Common css

```css
.container{
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,minmax(40px,auto));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
@media only screen
  and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 10px auto 10px;
      grid-template-rows: 10px auto 10px auto 10px auto 10px;
      background-color: grey;
    }
    
    #title {
      grid-column: 2 / 3;
      grid-row: 2 / 3;
    }
    
    #picture {
      grid-column: 2 / 3;
      grid-row: 4 / 5;
      min-height: 80px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
      
    #content {
      grid-column: 2 / 3;
      grid-row: 6 / 7;
    }
}

@media only screen
  and (min-width: 481px) {
    body {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
      grid-template-rows: auto auto;
      background-color: grey;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #title {
      grid-column: 2 / 3;
      grid-row: 1 / 2;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    #picture {
      grid-column: 1 / 2;
      grid-row: 1 / -1;
      min-height: 80px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
      
    #content {
      grid-column: 2 / 3;
      grid-row: 2 / 3;
      padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="title">Assets</div>
  <div id="picture">Picture here</div>
  <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</body>
```

use media queries to display a grid and define a deifferent grid and placement within media queries.

Comment: why downvote? it does exactly what the OP is trying to achieve. It will display on smartphones the hamburger layout.

Comment: because it's important to explain how it works rather than just pasting the code so that everyone can apply it to their own use cases

Answer (score -5):

Use this meta code in your `<head>`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: and what should that do? it will not change the layout of a grid from a normal display to a hamburger display. With the title being pushed above the picture even flexboxes will not work directly. Easiest way is the use of a grid while your line will not help at all.